@Transaction(timeout = 2) not working with R2DBC
I have Spring Boot application 3.2.5 application that connects to a Postgres DB, I'm using Spring reactor and R2DBCRepository.
I hava a Dao class that extends R2dbcRepository
interface ListDao extends R2dbcRepository<ListEntity, UUID> {

}

A repository where I have a method that has the @Transaction annotation
@Repository
class GeneralListRepository {

 @Autowired
 private ListDao dao;

 @Transactional(timeout = 1)
    public Mono<GeneralList> createGeneralList(GeneralList list) {
        return dao.save(new ListEntity(list))
                .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
     }

}

This is being called from the Service layer
@Service
class GeneralListRepository {

    public Mono<GeneralList> createList(GeneralList list) {
        return repository.createGeneralList(list);
     }
}

My code is some more complex that this, but the point is that I'm expecting to see a timeout due to the .delayElement, which I don't see... in my current code there is a set of inserts that can take longer that 15 sec... so I have a timeout of 10s but it's not working...
I've tested this using ToxyProxy to add a latency as well, but still this does not timeout...
In the other hand, is there a default transaction timeout when using R2DBC? I've tested delaying the response for about 5 min... but still does not timeout, I was expecting 30s...
